# Final attribute vs. a Private attribute with no Setter method in Java

Tags: java, oop

In Java, I feel that using Private when declaring an attribute and not declaring a Setter method for it gives the same outcome as using Final when declaring the attribute, both allow the variable to stay constant.

If that is the case, what is the benefit of using Final in this scenario?

Comment: Well, it's not the same because you might change the private attribute from inside your class since it's private and not final.

Answer (score 1):

Even without a setter other methods in the class can change the attribute so it's a completely different concept.
Many would argue it's not a good thing to do (it adds "side effects" to your program) but it's still possible.

Comment: Also if it's a codebase that has many programmers working on it, a programmer working on the code may introduce a  change that modifies the private variable from inside the class without questioning their action since the private member is not explicitly marked final.

Answer (score 1):

Assumed you are talking about variables, the keywords `final` and `private` define different characteristics.

The keyword `final` denies any changes to the variable and throws **`compilation errors`** when modified or changed. However, without specifying `public` or `private`, with the **default `package-private` access modifier**, it could be accessed by other classes **in the same `package`** once initialized **(text with `bold` fonts are corrected by @[charsofire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17795888/chaosfire) and @[MC Emperor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507738/mc-emperor))**.

On the other hand, the keyword `private` rejects the idea of being called by other classes, even in the same package. But it could be changed and modified by methods in the same class, even without `setter` or `getter` methods.

For example in the same `class` of the same `package`:

```
public class Student {
    private int score;

    final int id;

    public Student(int id, int score) {
        this.id = id;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public void modifyGrade(int newScore) {
        // Accepted
        this.score += newScore;
    }

    public void modifyID(int id) {
        // Rejected
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And in different `class` of the same `package`:

```
public class School {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student = new Student(0, 35);
        
        // Accepted
        System.out.println(student.id);
        // Rejected
        System.out.println(student.score);

        // Accepted
        student.modifyGrade(29);
        
        // throws exception
        student.id = 5;
        // Not visible
        student.score = 29;
    }    
}
```

Hope this answer helps you well,

and many thanks again to both @[charsofire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17795888/chaosfire) and @[MC Emperor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507738/mc-emperor), who helped to clarify significantly in this answer.

Comment: The keyword `final` denies any changes to the variable and throws exception when modified or changed - not true. Attempting to reassign final variable leads to **compilation** error, not exception, but you can change its' internal state.

Comment: However, without specifying `public` or `private`, by default, it could be accessed by other classes once initialized - also somewhat wrong. `Default` access modifier allows access to classes in the same package, but those not in package can't access it. `Protected` modifier allows access to classes in the same package and to inheritors, even if they are in another package.

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications, it appears that my concept towards `errors` and `exceptions`, as well as the keyword `default`, is not clear.

Comment: @hokwanhung No the keyword `default` is **not** used in the context of access modifiers. The *absence* of an access modifier makes it the 'default' access level (better known as *package-private*).

Comment: I realised that when double-checking on the Internet to fix the answer, and my wording was wrong. It should be called access modifier `default`  instead of the keyword `default`, which could mean the one in a `switch` block. Thank you @MC Emperor as well for clarification. Many thanks!

Comment: It's even better to call it *package-private*, as it avoids confusion with the `default` keyword (which is not only used with `switch` blocks, but also for default methods and annotation default values).

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help, and I surely learned something new and interesting. I shall go modifying the answer. And great thanks again to you and @Charsofire.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [`Encapsulation`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdev/Java-overview.html#GUID-68EE1A7B-1F78-4074-AB76-AF9B2CE878F6)

Consider this.

```java
public class Point
{

    int x, y;

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

    }

    //no getters or setters needed, I can just modify or read x and y directly.

}
```

```java
public class FinalPoint
{

    public final Point point;

    public FinalPoint(int x, int y)
    {

        this.point = new Point(x, y);

    }

    //no getters needed, I'll just read point since it is public

}
```

Right now, this `FinalPoint` has a final `Point` as an instance field. On the one hand, it means that that instance field cannot be reassigned. However, the fields of that instance field can definitely be reassigned.

For example.

```java
FinalPoint p = new FinalPoint(1, 2);
p.point.x = 4; //I have now modified state! final did not protect us here
```

The `final` keyword is powerful, but it does not mean that your data is unchangeable. It only means that that surface level reference is unchangeable - it will force a reference to always point to the same object. That does not stop the object its pointing to from changing it's internal state as much as it wants. The only guarantee `final` makes is that you always be pointing at the same object.

Which brings us to encapsulation. Encapsulation was created to solve this exact problem and more.

Consider this.

```java
public class EncapsulatedPoint
{

    private Point point;

    public EncapsulatedPoint(int x, int y)
    {

        this.point = new Point(x, y);

    }

    public int getX() { return this.point.x; }
    public int getY() { return this.point.y; }

}
```

Now, because I have encapsulated `Point` and exposed only the data I can safely expose, I have protected myself from modification. It is ***impossible*** to change this object (without using reflection or other hacks the designers are actively removing). It truly is [Immutable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html).

Of course, Encapsulation is not superior to using `final`. There is a time and a place for both. Knowing when and where allows you to make your software secure.

Comment: Encapsulation and immutability are orthogonal concepts. It would be less confusing to answer without conflating these two.

Comment: That's fair. I just struggle to see a better way to describe it. I was taught the 2 at the same time, so for me, they work together to achieve the real goal - preventing runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

Private variables will never access from the outside of the class and  Final will never change by taking input from the user.